# Is there a kanji for いいですね?

Tags: translation, kanji, nuances, readings, adjectives

Is there kanji for いいですね?

I see that よいですね can be written as 良いですね.

In context, is 良いですね understood and read as いいですね?

Answer (score 2):

いいですね is a conversational expression which can be used with the meaning "That sounds good!", "Good idea!", "Great!", etc. When used in this sense, I would think most people would write it with *kana*. (Often it would be strange to say よいですね instead.)

On the other hand, writing 良いですね can also be read いいですね, but it feels like 良い is used with a more precise meaning of "good" (as opposed to "not good" or "bad"). So 良いですね looks like it should be used *when it could also be read as* よいですね (without sounding out-of-place).

So, いいですね can sometimes be written 良いですね, but I would think there are also uses of いいですね where it is better written in *kana*.